# Background images not displayed on html page after add file web.config with Redirect rule

Tags: html, iis

We use IIS for hosting web site.

The task: when the site is updated, appool in IIS switches to a page stub, with the text "Site is updated" and return the user from the page for example https://mysite.dev.com/page1/ to https://mysite.dev.com/.

Created a simple HTML page (stub) with a picture as the background.

Created a *web.config* file with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rewrite to root" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="." />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^([^.]+)\.dev\.com$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}.dev.com/" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true"  />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Update site</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <style>
   body {
    background-image: url("images/bg.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-y;
    background-position: center center;
    }
   h1 {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center; 
    left: 50%;
    top: 25%; 
    color: #3C362B;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 4em;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: 'Mistral', cursive;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
   p {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center; 
    left: 50%;
    top: 45%;
    color: #3C362B;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: 'Brush Script MT', cursive;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Update site</h1>
    <p>We apologize for any inconvenience. Work on the update is underway. The site will be available soon</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Everything works correctly, before add a *web.config* file with a rule - result, does not show the picture as background, only text is displayed.

There are no 404 errors or anything in the browser.

The open sources have not found the case for the solution, please help find the solution.
What do I do wrong?

**Updated:**
File web.config creating automatically when creating a rule in IIS

Comment: What is web.config? How and where is it used?

Comment: the file is created by IIS when the rule is created

Comment: could you right-click on the link and open a new tab to see what path it is referring to? also enable failed request tracing logs and share the details with us. try to give the full path for the image and see the result

Comment: @Jalpa Panchal 
Changing the path does not affect the display of the background unless the path is correct and the 404 file is not found. 
When you delete a web.config, everything is displayed, even if you change paths. The IIS Module Rewrite was reinstalled, but after the rule was created no logs were created in the folder FailedRequestTracing.
as if the redirect rule does not allow the content static

Comment: If i set ```background-image: url('../images/bg.jpg');``` i get 404 error in chrome F12
if i set ```background-image: url('/images/bg.jpg');```  i get 301 Moved Permanently
but image is not available, background blank

Comment: @Константин what is the actual path for the images?

Comment: @Jalpa Panchal what is the actual path? bg.jpg is located in the project in the images folder.
```C:/inetpub/wwwroot/update/images/bg.jpg``` is a actual path. 
I tried to put bg.jpg next to index.html with changing path, nothing works out.

Comment: actual path ``` background-image: url("../update/images/bg.jpg");``` also does not work when the rule is turned on. If you delete the rule - everything works and shows well. I do not understand this magic

Comment: magic, if you create a copy of the directory with the site, and specify the addresses in the html page for example instead 
```background-image: url("../update/images/bg.jpg");``` to
``` background-image: url("../update_new/images/bg.jpg");``` 
 works and redirects and displays the page background

Comment: could you please enable freb and share the logs snapshot here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know what happened, but in my post helped to convert the picture to base64 and insert the code to html, only then everything works correctly.